# Landscape and table formatting

Tags: formatting, landscape

[image]I have written a latex code, but the table turns out to be weird. Please help. Thanks!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE,labelsep=newline,
aboveskip=0pt,font=bf,justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape,threeparttablex}
 \usepackage{everypage}

\newcommand{\Lpagenumber}{\ifdim\textwidth=\linewidth\else\bgroup
\dimendef\margin=0
\ifodd\value{page}\margin=\oddsidemargin
\else\margin=\evensidemargin
\fi
\raisebox{\dimexpr -\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-0.5\linewidth}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \rlap{\hspace{\dimexpr \margin+\textheight+\footskip}%
        \llap{\rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}%
\egroup\fi}
\AddEverypageHook{\Lpagenumber}%


\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\gmc}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{@{}#2@{}}{#3}}

\begin{document}

\begingroup % keep any font size changes local to group
%\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default value: 6pt

\begin{landscape}
    \thispagestyle{empty}   
    \captionof{table}{U.S. Corporate Employees and the Supply of Real Estate Properties Available for Sale}
    \singlespacing
    \small
    \setlength\tabcolsep{6pt} %default
    %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.95}

    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l*{18}{Y}@{}}
        \toprule
    \gmc{19}{c}{Total Across All Regions} \\\midrule
     Begi. of Year & \gmc{3}{c}{2010} & \gmc{3}{c}{2011} & \gmc{3}{c}{2012} & \gmc{3}{c}{2013} & \gmc{3}{c}{2014} & \gmc{3}{c}{2015} \\\cmidrule(l){2-19}
     & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} \\

     & Employees & Supply & Ratio & Employees & Supply & Ratio & Employees & Supply & Ratio & Employees & Supply & Ratio & Employees & Supply & Ratio & Employees & Supply & Ratio \\\hline
     All Regions&   32,634,908& 1,632,728&  20&     33,092,790& 1,720,278&  19  &   33,829,341& 1,585,138&  21  &   34,505,039& 1,166,609&  30  &   35,333,058& 1,123,050&  31&     35,932,126& 1,123,834&  32 \\\hline\\\hline
    \gmc{19}{c}{Analysis at the Metropolitan Level} \\\hline
     Begi. of Year & \gmc{3}{c}{2010} & \gmc{3}{c}{2011} & \gmc{3}{c}{2012}               & \gmc{3}{c}{2013} & \gmc{3}{c}{2014} & \gmc{3}{c}{2015} \\\cline{2-19}
    & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} \\
    & Employees & Supply & Ratio & Employees & Supply & Ratio & Employees & Supply & Ratio & Employees & Supply & Ratio & Employees & Supply & Ratio & Employees & Supply & Ratio \\\hline
    Phoenix&    367,499&    54,788& 7&      394,999&    62,654& 6&      407,725 &51,918&    8&      375,802&    35,952& 10  &   360,115&    40,973& 9&      378,757 &40,269&    9 \\
    Los Angeles&    1,003,169&  59,889& 17  &   1,056,392&  59,025& 18&     1,012,073&  52,726& 19&     1,018,180&  25,563& 40&     924,787&    25,493& 36&     900,258&    29,195& 31\\
    San Diego&  180,285&    19,940& 9   &   172,393 &24,345&    7   &   172,272&    23,137& 7   &   171,815&    12,607& 14&     161,064 &11,844&    14&     157,810&    13,440& 12\\
    San Francisco&  2,268,842&  29,832& 76&     2,347,845&  31,880& 74  &   2,461,445&  27,843& 88  &   2,545,909&  14,817& 172 &   2,602,896&  14,979& 174&        2,550,790&  16,163& 158\\
    Denver& 475,575&    50,967& 9&      492,016&    52,426& 9   &   537,333&    43,835& 12  &   607,872&    32,378& 19&     615,280&    31,683& 19  &   639,383&    27,716& 23\\
    Washington& 2,540,156&  93,419& 27&     2,486,800&  99,547& 25&     2,471,481&  91,452& 27  &   2,458,657&  68,954& 36  &   2,534,375&  68,775& 37  &   2,530,747&  76,055& 33\\
    Miami&  477,658&    80,343& 6&      507,007&    91,758& 6&      365,279&    81,908& 4&      376,885&    54,883& 7&      376,250&    50,283& 7&      395,997 &50,333 &8\\
    Tampa&  689,823&    123,427 &6&     730,273&    132,552&    6&      884,770&    107,814&    8&      954,829&    75,111& 13  &   1,004,677&  78,760& 13&     930,456&    78,590& 12\\
    Atlanta &2,836,287& 173,254&    16&     2,825,611&  175,955&    16  &   2,917,257&  165,493&    18&     2,937,585&  121,428 &24&        3,083,928&  119,230&    26&     3,140,758&  120,336&    26\\
    Chicago &4,244,670& 173,213&    25&     4,364,844&  179,824&    24&     4,572,732&  168,134&    27&     4,672,606&  127,218&    37&     4,717,841&  115,975&    41&     4,771,327&  118,183 &40\\
    Boston& 1,406,473&  57,299& 25  &   1,417,301&  58,438& 24&     1,392,619&  65,126& 21  &   1,468,621&  51,300& 29  &   1,478,784&  46,418& 32&     1,557,034&  46,873& 33\\
    Detroit&    1,300,213&  64,128& 20&     1,356,644&  55,783& 24  &   1,378,934&  46,452& 30&     1,427,418&  37,303& 38  &   1,446,164&  35,845  &40 &   1,512,823&  37,522& 40\\
    Minneapolis&    1,665,563&  44,115& 38&     1,684,094&  48,546& 35  &   1,714,084&  44,109& 39&     1,627,984&  32,231& 51  &   1,665,597&  32,053& 52&     1,651,004&  32,406& 51\\
    Charlotte&  1,005,165&  125,320&    8&      1,017,866&  130,024&    8&      1,047,660&  124,601&    8&      1,045,522&  103,693 &10 &   1,096,008&  103,404&    11  &   1,135,282&  96,547& 12\\
    Las Vegas&  298,798&    21,624& 14&     307,775&    22,605& 14&     314,001&    20,021& 16&     322,573&    10,092& 32&     324,823&    12,433& 26  &   330,772&    13,048& 25\\
    New York&   5,662,806&  159,197&    36&     5,754,068&  166,138&    35&     5,844,228&  181,279&    32&     5,962,398&  138,905&    43  &   6,032,939&  127,497&    47&     6,098,428&  130,815&    47\\
    Cleveland&  2,080,563&  60,757& 34  &   2,156,766&  70,892& 30  &   2,147,721&  67,481& 32&     2,183,454&  55,386& 39&     2,122,614&  52,631& 40  &   2,161,265&  50,718& 43\\
    Portland&   162,390&    34,946& 5&      180,935&    34,058& 5&      197,258&    30,306& 7&      218,717&    20,653& 11  &   363,575&    20,881& 17&     531,026&    20,351& 26\\
    Dallas& 3,349,506&  167,786&    20&     3,205,328&  181,931&    18&     3,296,765&  152,138&    22&     3,331,824&  122,333 &27&        3,521,591&  107,722&    33  &   3,585,203&  101,505 &35\\
    Seattle&    619,467&    38,484& 16  &   633,834&    41,897& 15&     693,705&    39,365& 18  &   796,388 &25,802&    31&     899,751&    26,171& 34  &   973,008&    23,769& 41\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}   

    \thispagestyle{empty} \small \hrule \medskip 
    Notes: The table reports the sum of corporate employees for firms headquartered across the United States and the supply of residential real estate properties available for sale. Data on number of employees (Compustat: EMP) are from the Compustat North America Fundamentals Annual File (WRDS: FUNDA) available from WRDS, where I sum number of employees by fiscal year (Compustat: FYEAR). Housing supply data are from Zillow. To classify firms' corporate employees and Zillow's real estate supply into Case-Shiller regions, I follow the same sort procedure used for developing the regional accounting profitability indices. That is, based on firms' headquarters location or the Zillow's zip code, respectively, using: (a) a zip-code-coordinates mapping from the Census Gazetteer File, (b) regional coordinates from Google searches, and (c) the spherical distance of a firm's headquarters to its closest Case-Shiller region. Using firms in each region, I construct annual sums of corporate employees. Both corporate employees and properties supply refer to the beginning of each year, and thus the Compustat data are as of Dec. 31, 2009 through Dec. 31, 2014, and the Zillow data are from beginning of Jan. 2010 through beginning of Jan. 2015. The series begin in Jan. 2010, the first month with available housing supply data.

    \medskip
    \hrule
\end{landscape}
\endgroup

 \end{document}
```

Comment: "able turns out to be weird" isn't a useful description, please say what you want to happen and what does happen

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am surprised that toprule does not even cover caption. I am not sure the reason for that. Thanks.

Comment: even before I look at the output tex is screaming `Overfull \hbox (151.63504pt too wide) in alignment at lines 73--73` which explains most of the problems it should be `begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}` but as I said in a comment on your previous question I'd never use tabularx for this (and I wrote tabularx)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. So you will use tabular environment. Is there any advantage of tabular over tabularx? What about alignment to text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's still too big really but this will get you started, `tabularx` does nothing useful here so I removed it.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{setspace,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[tablename=TABLE,labelsep=newline,
aboveskip=0pt,font=bf,justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdflscape,threeparttablex}
 \usepackage{everypage}

\newcommand{\Lpagenumber}{\ifdim\textwidth=\linewidth\else\bgroup
\dimendef\margin=0
\ifodd\value{page}\margin=\oddsidemargin
\else\margin=\evensidemargin
\fi
\raisebox{\dimexpr -\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-0.5\linewidth}[0pt][0pt]{%
    \rlap{\hspace{\dimexpr \margin+\textheight+\footskip}%
        \llap{\rotatebox{90}{\thepage}}}}%
\egroup\fi}
\AddEverypageHook{\Lpagenumber}%


%\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand{\gmc}[3]{\multicolumn{#1}{@{}#2@{}}{\makebox[0pt][#2]{#3}}}

\begin{document}

% not needed \begingroup % keep any font size changes local to group
%\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % default value: 6pt

\begin{landscape}
    \thispagestyle{empty}   
    \captionof{table}{U.S. Corporate Employees and the Supply of Real Estate Properties Available for Sale}
    \singlespacing
    \footnotesize
     \def\Ratio{\makebox[0pt][r]{R.}}
    \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} %default

    %\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.95}

    \hspace*{-15pt}%
     \begin{tabular}{@{}l*{18}{r}@{}}
        \toprule
    \gmc{19}{c}{Total Across All Regions} \\\midrule
     Begi. of Year & \gmc{3}{c}{2010} & \gmc{3}{c}{2011} & \gmc{3}{c}{2012} & \gmc{3}{c}{2013} & \gmc{3}{c}{2014} & \gmc{3}{c}{2015} \\\cmidrule(l){2-19}
     & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} \\

     & Employees & Supply & \Ratio & Employees & Supply & \Ratio & Employees & Supply & \Ratio & Employees & Supply & \Ratio & Employees & Supply & \Ratio & Employees & Supply & \Ratio \\\hline
     All Regions&   32,634,908& 1,632,728&  20&     33,092,790& 1,720,278&  19  &   33,829,341& 1,585,138&  21  &   34,505,039& 1,166,609&  30  &   35,333,058& 1,123,050&  31&     35,932,126& 1,123,834&  32 \\\hline\\\hline
    \gmc{19}{c}{Analysis at the Metropolitan Level} \\\hline
     Begi. of Year & \gmc{3}{c}{2010} & \gmc{3}{c}{2011} & \gmc{3}{c}{2012}               & \gmc{3}{c}{2013} & \gmc{3}{c}{2014} & \gmc{3}{c}{2015} \\\cline{2-19}
    & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} & \gmc{3}{c}{Corporate Properties} \\
    & Employees & Supply & \Ratio & Employees & Supply & \Ratio & Employees & Supply & \Ratio & Employees & Supply & \Ratio & Employees & Supply & \Ratio & Employees & Supply & \Ratio \\\hline
    Phoenix&    367,499&    54,788& 7&      394,999&    62,654& 6&      407,725 &51,918&    8&      375,802&    35,952& 10  &   360,115&    40,973& 9&      378,757 &40,269&    9 \\
    Los Angeles&    1,003,169&  59,889& 17  &   1,056,392&  59,025& 18&     1,012,073&  52,726& 19&     1,018,180&  25,563& 40&     924,787&    25,493& 36&     900,258&    29,195& 31\\
    San Diego&  180,285&    19,940& 9   &   172,393 &24,345&    7   &   172,272&    23,137& 7   &   171,815&    12,607& 14&     161,064 &11,844&    14&     157,810&    13,440& 12\\
    San Francisco&  2,268,842&  29,832& 76&     2,347,845&  31,880& 74  &   2,461,445&  27,843& 88  &   2,545,909&  14,817& 172 &   2,602,896&  14,979& 174&        2,550,790&  16,163& 158\\
    Denver& 475,575&    50,967& 9&      492,016&    52,426& 9   &   537,333&    43,835& 12  &   607,872&    32,378& 19&     615,280&    31,683& 19  &   639,383&    27,716& 23\\
    Washington& 2,540,156&  93,419& 27&     2,486,800&  99,547& 25&     2,471,481&  91,452& 27  &   2,458,657&  68,954& 36  &   2,534,375&  68,775& 37  &   2,530,747&  76,055& 33\\
    Miami&  477,658&    80,343& 6&      507,007&    91,758& 6&      365,279&    81,908& 4&      376,885&    54,883& 7&      376,250&    50,283& 7&      395,997 &50,333 &8\\
p    Tampa&  689,823&    123,427 &6&     730,273&    132,552&    6&      884,770&    107,814&    8&      954,829&    75,111& 13  &   1,004,677&  78,760& 13&     930,456&    78,590& 12\\
    Atlanta &2,836,287& 173,254&    16&     2,825,611&  175,955&    16  &   2,917,257&  165,493&    18&     2,937,585&  121,428 &24&        3,083,928&  119,230&    26&     3,140,758&  120,336&    26\\
    Chicago &4,244,670& 173,213&    25&     4,364,844&  179,824&    24&     4,572,732&  168,134&    27&     4,672,606&  127,218&    37&     4,717,841&  115,975&    41&     4,771,327&  118,183 &40\\
    Boston& 1,406,473&  57,299& 25  &   1,417,301&  58,438& 24&     1,392,619&  65,126& 21  &   1,468,621&  51,300& 29  &   1,478,784&  46,418& 32&     1,557,034&  46,873& 33\\
    Detroit&    1,300,213&  64,128& 20&     1,356,644&  55,783& 24  &   1,378,934&  46,452& 30&     1,427,418&  37,303& 38  &   1,446,164&  35,845  &40 &   1,512,823&  37,522& 40\\
    Minneapolis&    1,665,563&  44,115& 38&     1,684,094&  48,546& 35  &   1,714,084&  44,109& 39&     1,627,984&  32,231& 51  &   1,665,597&  32,053& 52&     1,651,004&  32,406& 51\\
    Charlotte&  1,005,165&  125,320&    8&      1,017,866&  130,024&    8&      1,047,660&  124,601&    8&      1,045,522&  103,693 &10 &   1,096,008&  103,404&    11  &   1,135,282&  96,547& 12\\
    Las Vegas&  298,798&    21,624& 14&     307,775&    22,605& 14&     314,001&    20,021& 16&     322,573&    10,092& 32&     324,823&    12,433& 26  &   330,772&    13,048& 25\\
    New York&   5,662,806&  159,197&    36&     5,754,068&  166,138&    35&     5,844,228&  181,279&    32&     5,962,398&  138,905&    43  &   6,032,939&  127,497&    47&     6,098,428&  130,815&    47\\
    Cleveland&  2,080,563&  60,757& 34  &   2,156,766&  70,892& 30  &   2,147,721&  67,481& 32&     2,183,454&  55,386& 39&     2,122,614&  52,631& 40  &   2,161,265&  50,718& 43\\
    Portland&   162,390&    34,946& 5&      180,935&    34,058& 5&      197,258&    30,306& 7&      218,717&    20,653& 11  &   363,575&    20,881& 17&     531,026&    20,351& 26\\
    Dallas& 3,349,506&  167,786&    20&     3,205,328&  181,931&    18&     3,296,765&  152,138&    22&     3,331,824&  122,333 &27&        3,521,591&  107,722&    33  &   3,585,203&  101,505 &35\\
    Seattle&    619,467&    38,484& 16  &   633,834&    41,897& 15&     693,705&    39,365& 18  &   796,388 &25,802&    31&     899,751&    26,171& 34  &   973,008&    23,769& 41\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}%  
    \hspace*{-15pt}%

    \thispagestyle{empty} \small \hrule \medskip 
    Notes: The table reports the sum of corporate employees for firms headquartered across the United States and the supply of residential real estate properties available for sale. Data on number of employees (Compustat: EMP) are from the Compustat North America Fundamentals Annual File (WRDS: FUNDA) available from WRDS, where I sum number of employees by fiscal year (Compustat: FYEAR). Housing supply data are from Zillow. To classify firms' corporate employees and Zillow's real estate supply into Case-Shiller regions, I follow the same sort procedure used for developing the regional accounting profitability indices. That is, based on firms' headquarters location or the Zillow's zip code, respectively, using: (a) a zip-code-coordinates mapping from the Census Gazetteer File, (b) regional coordinates from Google searches, and (c) the spherical distance of a firm's headquarters to its closest Case-Shiller region. Using firms in each region, I construct annual sums of corporate employees. Both corporate employees and properties supply refer to the beginning of each year, and thus the Compustat data are as of Dec. 31, 2009 through Dec. 31, 2014, and the Zillow data are from beginning of Jan. 2010 through beginning of Jan. 2015. The series begin in Jan. 2010, the first month with available housing supply data.

    \medskip
    \hrule
\end{landscape}
% no \endgroup

 \end{document}
```